# WCF Newbie Question: Calling Methods from JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, wcf

Greetings!

I'm new to WCF and I thought it would be similar to ASP.NET web services, but I'm unable to call a method from client-side JavaScript.  My web form looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
         <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/test.js" />
         </Scripts>
         <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MyService.svc" />
         </Services>
      </asp:ScriptManager>
   </div>
   <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

My service's interface looks like this:

```
namespace Test
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "Test")]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();

        [OperationContract]
        string SayHi();
    }
}
```

And here's its implementation:

```
namespace Test
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }

        public string SayHi()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the JavaScript:

```
function test() {
    Test.MyService.SayHi(SayHiSuccess, SayHiError);
}

function SayHiSuccess(result) {
    alert(result[0]);
}

function SayHiError(error) {
    alert(error.toString());
}
```

It appears that the service's SayHi() method never executes, although I'm not sure why or how to being troubleshooting.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't post your web.config contents. What binding are you using? You should probably be using [`webHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx).

Also, it may help to know your .svc file contents. Although I've never tried it, I understand that you don't have to modify web.config at all if you use [`WebScriptServiceHostFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webscriptservicehostfactory.aspx) as your service host factory. That's as simple as modifying your .svc file as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyService"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"
 %>
```

If all else fails, here are some resources for you:

- [Calling WCF Service from Javascript](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html)
- [Create a Simple WCF Web...](http://peterkellner.net/2008/09/14/wcf-web-service-json-vs2008/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. Should be working by right. You could try adding the WebService and the WebMethod attributes as well.

For debugging a WCF web service I normally use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to track HTTP calls while running the WCF code with a debugger attached (run in Visual Studio in most cases).