# Calling from javascript to WCF

Tags: ajax, wcf

I created a WCF service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ISTL
{
    public class MatchesListService : IMatchesListService
    {
        public bool AcceptRequestToChangeMatchTime(int matchId)
        {
            return MatchesListManager.AcceptRequestToChangeMatchTime(matchId);
        }
    }
}
```

That implements this contract:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ISTL
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "ISTL")]
    public interface IMatchesListService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool AcceptRequestToChangeMatchTime(int matchId);
    }
}
```

And this is in the web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ISTL.MatchesListService">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ISTL.IMatchesListService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And in the masterPage:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MatchesListService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I am trying to call my WCF service from my javascript code:

```
ISTL.IMatchesListService.AcceptRequestToChangeMatchTime(matchId);
```

But calling the WCF fails.
When I debug with FireBug, when I reach the calling line, then the error occurs. matchId is a valid value.
FireBug recognizes the ISTL namespace, but regarding IMatchesListService it says its value is 'undefiend'.

Someone know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks for helping !

Comment: you need to pass onSuccess , onFailure delgate check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712238/wcf-newbie-question-calling-methods-from-javascript                                                                                                                         I would recommend you to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass onSuccess , onFailure delgate check this [WCF Newbie Question: Calling Methods from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712238/wcf-newbie-question-calling-methods-from-javascript) … I would recommend you to close this question.

Comment: I have read the question in that post before posting my issue.
The delegates to onSuccess and onFailure are not mandatory. The call should occur also without them.
But anyway I tried adding the delegates now, and the problem persists.